# javascript access form data from inside mongoose schema hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a form which I have separated its content into two mongodb schema

I would like to read variables which are inside node.js/express.js directly in mongoose schema hooks 
either through the pre or post hooks of the schema. these are my files

express.js

```
var firstName = req.body.first_name;
var lastName = req.body.last_name;
var fullName = firstName+' '+lastName;
var employmentDate = req.body.employment_date;
var responsibility = req.body.responsibility;

userschema.full_name = fullName;
userschema.first_name = firstName;
userschema.last_name = lastName;
userschema.save(function (err, result){

});
/******************express UPDATE START**********/
    user  = new userschema(req.body)
    employment = new employmentObject(req.body)

    employment.employment_date= employmentDate;
    employment.responsibility= responsibility;
/******************express UPDATE ENDS**********/
```

Schema.js

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        full_name           : String,
        other_name          : String,
        last_name           : String,
        email               : String
        });

userSchema.pre('save', function (){
    //obtain values from form field
    var field1 = employmentDate;
    var field2 = responsibility;

    const employmentObject = this.model('employment-detail');   
    /******************schema UPDATE START**********/
    var emp_Date = employmentObject.employment_date;
    var duties = employmentObject.responsibility;
    /******************schema UPDATE ENDS**********/

    employmentObjectins = new employmentObject({
                                'employment_date': formField1,
                                'responsibility' :formField2
                        });

        employmentObjectins.save(function (err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err+' error saving object');
        }
        else{
            console.log('no error in saving object');
        }
    });
});
```

This is the just the summarized content, it is longer than this. But this is the main concept.
The major areas is in getting express.js content into the model's schema

**UPDATE**

employmentDate and responsibility is not in the userSchema but it is in the employmentSchema
How can I get the fields which are not in userSchema (the main schema) but are in the employmentSchema
( the second schema)

**SECOND UPDATE**

With the modification above it is producing error
 ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document:

What am i doing wrong

**THIRD UPDATE**

When I made modification based on what you said, I discovered that when I have two models 
declared in express.js with their model fields/variables and I call the second model in the 
pre hook of the first model it was giving me this error
**Can\'t save() the same doc multiple times in parallel.**

After making modification to the code. These are the files which exist

Express.js

```
var firstName = req.body.first_name;
var lastName = req.body.last_name;
var fullName = firstName+' '+lastName;
var employmentDate = req.body.employment_date;
var responsibility = req.body.responsibility;

userschema.full_name = fullName;
userschema.first_name = firstName;
userschema.last_name = lastName;
userschema.save(function (err, result){

});

employment.employment_date= employmentDate; <---
employment.responsibility= responsibility; <---
//I believe that I would need to declared this in order to use it in the schema

user  = new userschema(req.body)
employment = new employmentObject(req.body)
```

userschema.js

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        full_name           : String,
        other_name          : String,
        last_name           : String,
        email               : String
        });

userSchema.pre('save', function (){
    //obtain values from form field
    var field1 = employmentDate;
    var field2 = responsibility;

    const employmentObject = this.model('employment-detail');   
    var emp_Date = employmentObject.employment_date;<-- I am calling what I declared earlier
    var duties = employmentObject.responsibility;<-- I am calling what I declared earlier in express
   **//when I declared above two lines it brings up the error **
   **//Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel.**
    employmentObjectins = new employmentObject({
                                'employment_date': emp_Date,
                                'responsibility' :duties
                        });

        employmentObjectins.save(function (err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err+' error saving object');
        }
        else{
            console.log('no error in saving object');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do in my projects

```
let userData = new UserModel(req.body);
let employmentData = new EmploymentModel(req.body);
```

This will save all the parameters from `req.body` matching the schema

Comment: You are the boom. If matrix was true I would have through the computer given you a hug
Thank you very much, I am really grateful. 

Please What about fields that belongs to other models which are not in the main model
Please look at comment above

Comment: Thank you very much. I am currently getting an error 'Can\'t save() the same doc multiple times in parallel {a document id e.g.562422hkjhkjhjkhk}. I would get back to you with latest result

Comment: i have added the modification which produces the error **'Can\'t save() the same doc multiple times in parallel**

Comment: Its hard to tell what's causing the problem without seeing the code

Comment: Thank you very much I wanted to up vote your answer but I do not have enough points

Comment: Its okay. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please if you by any chance find a solution to the remaining part of question I would really apreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const crypto =  require('crypto')
const Userschema = new Schema({
    email:{
            type:String,
            unique:true,
            lowercase:true
    },
    name:String,
    password:String,
    picture:String,
    isSeller:{type:Boolean,default:false},
    address:{
        addr1:String,
        addr2:String,
        city:String,
        state:String,
        country:String,
        postalCode:String
    },
    created:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
});
// this pre function do encryption before saving the password into database
Userschema.pre('save',async function(next){
    var user  =this;
    console.log(user.password);
    if (!user.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    bcrypt.hash(user.password,null,null,(err,hash)=>{       
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
       user.password = hash;
        next();
       **this is my mistake I miss "next()"**
    })
})
```